# How to make 2 columns work together to be unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique, create-table

A customer, `cus_id` can own multiple houses. A house has a `house_num` by itself is not unique. However, together a `cus_id` and a `house_num` are unique. How can I make it so `cus_id` and `house_num` together are unique. So I can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` and won't have to worry that I am going to insert a duplicate

```
CREATE TABLE house(
    house_id                    int
                                NOT NULL
                                AUTO_INCREMENT
                                PRIMARY KEY,

    cus_id                      int
                                NOT NULL,
                                FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customers (cus_id),

    house_num                   int
                                NOT NULL
);
```

Example of a table

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| house_id | cus_id | house_num |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 |      3 |         4 |
|        2 |      3 |         5 |
|        3 |      8 |         4 |
|        4 |      9 |         2 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

However, this row  cannot exist as it would be a duplicate of `house_id` `2`

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        5 |      3 |         5 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a unique constraint on the combination of `cus_id` and `house_num`:

```
ALTER TABLE house ADD CONSTRAINT your_cnstr UNIQUE (cus_id, house_num);
```

Inside your `CREATE` statement you may try:

```
CREATE TABLE house (
    house_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cus_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customers (cus_id),
    house_num int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT your_cnstr UNIQUE (cus_id, house_num)
);
```

Comment: Any way to do this in the `create table` statement

Comment: Also does this mean I can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` and not have to worry about duplicates i my table

Comment: @James Check the updated answer to see how to do this at table creation time.  Yes, if you do an `INSERT INTO IGNORE` with the above constraint, MySQL will issue (and swallow) a silent error, but the insert operation would continue without formal error.  And no, there would not be any duplicates inserted into your table.

Comment: *if you do an INSERT INTO IGNORE with the above constraint, MySQL will issue (and swallow) a silent error, but the insert operation would continue without formal error.* This is slightly incorrect. Without IGNORE MySQL raises error whereas with it MySQL raises warning instead of error.